# Enable FormDataMultiPart or @FormDataParam in JAVAEE Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey

trying to implement some kind of image upload function I found internet sources recommending using FormDataMultiPart or FormDataParam with jersey.

Jersey is a nice webframework and part of javaee. My Problem is, that both interfaces are not available in my api. I use the javaee api from Maven javax.javaee-api version 7.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It seems that both are not part of javaee standard. My question is how to enable image upload with glassfish using javaee api. Best would be using some kind of workaround to enable image upload with jersey.

thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

Include the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To upload images just declare a POST method with an InputStream form data parameter, for example:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/uploadImage")
@Consumes(value = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream image)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that both are not part of javaee standard

I would say you are not entirely correct saying that. It would be true if you talk about GF3 and Jersey 1.11.x which is bundled with it. But if you take a look at [latest Jersey lib documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)
you would find it is a part of a standard now. You can use it with GF4.

Anyway [here](http://aruld.info/handling-multiparts-in-restful-applications-using-jersey/) you can find a complete example how to upload a file with Jersey v1.x. It is working with GS3 and 1.11.1 version of Jersey bundled with it.

if you want to use Jersey with GF4 to achieve this you may add these dependencies to your maven pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```